# Setting Trac with GIT receiving : "GIT backend not available"

Tags: git, trac

We are a small team that worked with `TRAC` + `SubVersion`,
post-commit hooks and all :)

Recently, we have a situation some developers need to work offline,
so all together we decided to move to `GIT` for it is more advanced altogether with the fact it is distributed.

We successfully converted all the repositories of all the project.
But unable to integrate `GIT` repository with its `TRAC` instance.

1 - set up `GIT` on a `Windows 7` `Apache 2.2` server
    per : http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/07/31/hosting-a-git-server-under-apache-on-windows

2 - Convert our repositories per : http://john.albin.net/git/convert-subversion-to-git

3 - Set up `TRAC` with `GIT` per : http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracGit

The repository is working can easily Clone/Pull/Push/Commit anything.

When I add the repository to `TRAC`,  I don't see the `"Browse Source"` and the revision.
when trying to `trac-admin <ENV> repository resync "(default)"`
I receive the error message: `TracError: GIT backend not available`

What gives?
Where can I see what's going on?
What am I missing?

Comment: Note: the same trac Env was working with SVN Before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

1. setting TRAC Log to DEBUG showed that TRAC Searched for GIT in c:\usr\bin\git
   which is definitely wrong, and a result of the UNIX defaults.

this caused failure in execution of --version and such.

2. setting `[git] git_bin=c:\program files (x86)\git\bin\git.exe
   Solved the situation.

Happy day